# Can we Move one storage account to another storage account in different tenant

Tags: azure, storage

I am looking to move one storage account from sub1 (from Tenant A) to sub2 (to Tenant B) on the same Azure account. Is this possible

Answer (score 1):

Moving storage accounts between tenants while keeping the storage account name is not possible. You would need to create a new storage account in the target tenant and then copy/move files over to the new storage account.

Your best option would be to use azcopy (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy) which is able to copy data directly from storage account to storage account (Blobs and Files only).

Answer (score 0):

I have an unconventional solution for this, note its just in case you need an unconventional solution. Currently we're closing 'TenantA' with a lot of subscriptions and old data not in use, but we still need to store some data for a few more months in 'TenantB'

1. Move storage account(s)/disks to a subscription not in use in TenantA
2. In the subscription, click 'change directory' and choose TenantB.
3. After 10 min ish all resources will be in TenantB with all its content. It seems they automatically get a '2' at the end of it to avoid any duplicate naming.
4. From here you may move them around using 'Change subscription'.

Remember moving subscriptions will remove some things such as roles, IAM etc, but data is retained. Ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/transfer-subscription#understand-the-impact-of-transferring-a-subscription

I just wanted to share this in case you face any limitations with AZcopy, it failed on me a few times, but changing directory, then using 'change subscription' worked better. Do be aware that you will have no backup using change directory.